# How to optimise this split-apply-combine using data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I recently attempted the following split-apply-combine task in `data.table` (my first) and I'd like to know if others have suggestions on how I might optimise it.

I have long data with one `obs_value` per classification, by sex, year and area. As part of my analysis I am dropping certain levels of `classif1` and wish to calculate a geometric mean of `obs_value` across the remaining levels of `classif1`.

## My data

```
>head(data)

           ref_area   sex            classif1 time obs_value
         1:      ABW SEX_T  AGE_5YRBANDS_TOTAL 2007     66.20
         2:      ABW SEX_T AGE_5YRBANDS_Y15-19 2007     24.35
         3:      ABW SEX_T AGE_5YRBANDS_Y20-24 2007     69.90
         4:      ABW SEX_T AGE_5YRBANDS_Y25-29 2007     85.72
         5:      ABW SEX_T AGE_5YRBANDS_Y30-34 2007     85.83
        ---                                                  
    228280:      ZWE SEX_M  AGE_YTHADULT_YGE25 2012     89.34
    228281:      ZWE SEX_F  AGE_YTHADULT_YGE15 2012     58.10
    228282:      ZWE SEX_F AGE_YTHADULT_Y15-64 2012     59.57
    228283:      ZWE SEX_F AGE_YTHADULT_Y15-24 2012     43.90
    228284:      ZWE SEX_F  AGE_YTHADULT_YGE25 2012     65.25
```

## Desired outcome

`AGE_5YRBANDS_GEOMEAN` should appear as a new category within `classif1`.

## My code

Using `library(psych)` for `geometric.mean`:

```
data.age.res.tmp <- data.age.res[, .(obs_value = geometric.mean(obs_value), classif1=classif1),by =.(ref_area, sex, time)][order(ref_area, sex, time, classif1)]
data.age.res.tmp <- data.age.res.tmp[,.SD[1], by =.(ref_area, sex, time)][order(ref_area, sex, time, classif1)]
data.age.res.tmp[, classif1:="AGE_5YRBANDS_MEAN*"]
data.age.res <- rbind(data.age.res, data.age.res.tmp)[order(ref_area, sex, time, classif1)]
rm(data.age.res.tmp)
```

## My result

```
>head(data.age.res)

   ref_area   sex            classif1 time obs_value
1:      ABW SEX_F  AGE_5YRBANDS_MEAN* 1991  64.55514
2:      ABW SEX_F AGE_5YRBANDS_Y20-24 1991  71.45000
3:      ABW SEX_F AGE_5YRBANDS_Y25-29 1991  76.96000
4:      ABW SEX_F AGE_5YRBANDS_Y30-34 1991  74.18000
5:      ABW SEX_F AGE_5YRBANDS_Y35-39 1991  68.84000
```

## My Question!

Can my code be optimised to remove the intermediate assignments, or improved in some other way?

## Edited to Add MWE

```
> dput(data.age.res[15751:15762])
structure(list(ref_area = c("GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", 
"GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR"), sex = c("SEX_F", 
"SEX_F", "SEX_F", "SEX_F", "SEX_F", "SEX_F", "SEX_F", "SEX_F", 
"SEX_F", "SEX_F", "SEX_F", "SEX_F"), classif1 = c("AGE_5YRBANDS_Y20-24", 
"AGE_5YRBANDS_Y25-29", "AGE_5YRBANDS_Y30-34", "AGE_5YRBANDS_Y35-39", 
"AGE_5YRBANDS_Y40-44", "AGE_5YRBANDS_Y50-54", "AGE_5YRBANDS_Y20-24", 
"AGE_5YRBANDS_Y25-29", "AGE_5YRBANDS_Y30-34", "AGE_5YRBANDS_Y35-39", 
"AGE_5YRBANDS_Y40-44", "AGE_5YRBANDS_Y50-54"), time = c(1990, 
1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991
), obs_value = c(75.63, 70.84, 69.4, 74.52, 78, 68.01, 73.73, 
70.5, 69.45, 74.16, 78.92, 68.35)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x5615381f73c0>)
```

Comment: @PeaceWang  MWE now refers to the same data.frame (`data.age.res`) as provided in my sample code.

Comment: `data.age.res[ , rbind(list(classif1 = "AGE_5YRBANDS_MEAN*", obs_value = mean(obs_value)), .SD), by = .(ref_area, sex, time)]`. If desired, sort columns (`setcolorder`) and rows (`setorder`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful try you can check by yourself.

```
data.age.res[, .(obs_value = geometric.mean(obs_value),
  classif1 = classif1),
  keyby = .(ref_area, sex, time)][,
    .SD[1],
    keyby = .(ref_area, sex, time)][, classif1 :=
      "AGE_5YRBANDS_MEAN*"][,
      rbind(data.age.res, .SD)][order(ref_area, sex, time, classif1)]
```

Data:

```
data.age.res <- structure(list(ref_area = c("GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", 
"GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR"), sex = c("SEX_F", 
"SEX_F", "SEX_F", "SEX_F", "SEX_F", "SEX_F", "SEX_F", "SEX_F", 
"SEX_F", "SEX_F", "SEX_F", "SEX_F"), classif1 = c("AGE_5YRBANDS_Y20-24", 
"AGE_5YRBANDS_Y25-29", "AGE_5YRBANDS_Y30-34", "AGE_5YRBANDS_Y35-39", 
"AGE_5YRBANDS_Y40-44", "AGE_5YRBANDS_Y50-54", "AGE_5YRBANDS_Y20-24", 
"AGE_5YRBANDS_Y25-29", "AGE_5YRBANDS_Y30-34", "AGE_5YRBANDS_Y35-39", 
"AGE_5YRBANDS_Y40-44", "AGE_5YRBANDS_Y50-54"), time = c(1990, 
1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991
), obs_value = c(75.63, 70.84, 69.4, 74.52, 78, 68.01, 73.73, 
70.5, 69.45, 74.16, 78.92, 68.35)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```